# Loading large amount of data using fusion table not working

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am totally new to google fusion table, just playing with it. I have imported a data of zip code boundaries into google fusion table. Now using the following code I am drawing the boundaries and its working fine

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                    select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
                    from: '1m9CwnJrCfWNHCEQQkxqcQBzp-dA-S9KB8vLTpCru',
                    where: 'ZCTA5CE10 in (25231,25501,25003)'
                },
                styles: [{
                    polygonOptions: _addStyle
                }]
            });
            layer.setMap(_this.mapData.map);
```

but the problem is I need to pass a lot of values in where command and when I do something like this, it fails

```
where: 'ZCTA5CE10 in (' + zipList + ')'
```

where zipList contains some 100+ list of comma separated zips. How can I draw this huge amount of data.
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r5jb6ew7/
see error in consoles.

Comment: Can you add a column containing a unique key you can use to select all of them (rather than using the number)?

Comment: No! I have to load boundaries of specific regions based on zip code.

Comment: you have no other option, you must reduce the size of the query, because the query will be sent via GET(and there is a limit for GET-requests, so it's basically no FusionTables-issue)